# how to I retrieve my results from this Enum Switch function?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, passwords

I have a basic tool that determines the strength of a password (not my code). I altered the code to retrieve the password we are testing from a `TextBox` (`textBox1`) when clicking `button1`. However, the label (Results) only ever shows results for weak or none. Wheat am I doing wrong here? How can I make the label reflect the results found in the `Enum` function `PasswordScore`?

Is there a simpler way of determining password strength that you guys have used?

```
public partial class Form7 : Form
{
    public Form7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public enum PasswordScore
    {
        Blank = 0,
        VeryWeak = 1,
        Weak = 2,
        Medium = 3,
        Strong = 4,
        VeryStrong = 5
    }

    public static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
    {
        int score = 0;
        if (password.Length == 0)
            return PasswordScore.Blank;
        if (password.Length < 4)
            return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;
        if (password.Length >= 8)
            score++;
        if (password.Length >= 12)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success &&
            Regex.Match(password, @"/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;

        return (PasswordScore)score;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String password = textBox1.Text; // Substitute with the user input string
        PasswordScore passwordStrengthScore = Form7.CheckStrength(password);
        switch (passwordStrengthScore)
        {
            case PasswordScore.Blank:
            case PasswordScore.VeryWeak:
            case PasswordScore.Weak:
                // Show an error message to the user
                break;
            case PasswordScore.Medium:
            case PasswordScore.Strong:
            case PasswordScore.VeryStrong:
                // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
                break;

        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Blank) { Result.Text = "Blank"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryWeak) { Result.Text = "Very Weak - FAIL"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Weak) { Result.Text = "Weak - FAIL"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Medium) { Result.Text = "Medium - Compliant"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Strong) { Result.Text = "Strong - Compliant"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryStrong) { Result.Text = "Very Strong - Compliant"; }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `int score = 0;` and step through the rest of the function line by line using the F10 key. Put a watch on `score` in the watch window. You'll see exactly what's happening. If that doesn't clear it up, try the same thing in `button1_Click`.

Comment: There is nothing to change Results in your sample of code - how do you expect it to be changed?

Comment: @NetMage I removed the if/then functions that applied the passwordStrengthScore results because it simply wont work. Thats why I am posting.

Answer (score 1):

The result is always weak or none because the regex in your case is always failing.

Please try to modify your regex. For e.g. :

```
if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
```

Modify to

```
if (Regex.Match(password, @"\d", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
```

And

```
Regex.Match(password, @"/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success
```

Modify to

```
Regex.Match(password, @"[a-z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success
```

Comment: That helped me get a bit further, awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code.

```
public partial class Form7 : Form
{
    public Form7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public enum PasswordScore
    {
        Blank = 0,
        VeryWeak = 1,
        Weak = 2,
        Medium = 3,
        Strong = 4,
        VeryStrong = 5
    }
    public static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
    {
        int score = 0;

        if (password.Length == 0)
            return PasswordScore.Blank;
        if (password.Length < 4)
            return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;

        if (password.Length >= 8)
            score++;
        if (password.Length >= 12)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"\d", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"[a-z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success &&
          Regex.Match(password, @"/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript).Success)
            score++;

        return (PasswordScore)score;
    }


    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String password = textBox1.Text; // Substitute with the user input string
        PasswordScore passwordStrengthScore = Form7.CheckStrength(password);

        switch (passwordStrengthScore)
        {
            case PasswordScore.Blank:
            case PasswordScore.VeryWeak:
            case PasswordScore.Weak:
                // Show an error message to the user
                break;
            case PasswordScore.Medium:
            case PasswordScore.Strong:
            case PasswordScore.VeryStrong:
                // Password deemed strong enough, allow user to be added to database etc
                break;
        }

        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Blank) { Result.Text = "Blank"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryWeak) { Result.Text = "Very Weak - FAIL"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Weak) { Result.Text = "Weak - FAIL"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Medium) { Result.Text = "Medium - Compliant"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.Strong) { Result.Text = "Strong - Compliant"; }
        if (passwordStrengthScore == PasswordScore.VeryStrong) { Result.Text = "Very Strong - Compliant"; }



    }
```

Comment: You still have / around your patterns, which is not valid for C#.